# Jquery popup with scrollbar and column alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm searching for a jquery popup that has a vertical scrollbar and that allows to show data as if it were imitating a Datagrid, except for the fact that rows are not visible.

I mean something like that should be showing in the popup

Field1      Field2       Field3

Value1      Value1       Value1

Value2      Value2       Value2

And if the lentgh of the elements that form the column is longer than the height of the screen a vertical scrollbar should display and allow to displace the values.

I've searched for it some time and I don't find anything, so I hope you can help me with this thing, as it seems to be very time consuming to do it from scratch.

Although I've been ordered to do it via jquery it doesn't really matter much as long as it works, so feel free to name other alternatives, that are more and less made, if they exist, the only limitation is that it has been done on client side using JavaScript as the rest of the code is done on that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, table doesn't display properly, I'm trying to improve it.

Comment: What about jquery dialog? Have you tried something already?Where is the code?

Answer (score 0):

For the dialog you could use jQuery UI. To meet the rest of the requirements just add a bit of css. Here you have an example of your case. I hope it helps you:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #dialog-content {
                height: 200px;
                /* Show scrolls if overflows! */
                overflow: scroll;
            }

            #dialog-content th,
            #dialog-content td {
                /* Big rows! */
                padding: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#dialog").dialog();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
            <div id="dialog-content">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Field1</th>
                            <th>Field2</th>
                            <th>Field3</th>
                            <th>Field4</th>
                            <th>Field5</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value1</td>
                            <td>Value2</td>
                            <td>Value3</td>
                            <td>Value4</td>
                            <td>Value5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value1</td>
                            <td>Value2</td>
                            <td>Value3</td>
                            <td>Value4</td>
                            <td>Value5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value1</td>
                            <td>Value2</td>
                            <td>Value3</td>
                            <td>Value4</td>
                            <td>Value5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Value1</td>
                            <td>Value2</td>
                            <td>Value3</td>
                            <td>Value4</td>
                            <td>Value5</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```